# transfere data from a database to another database which has been secured by a dmz with the help of firewall rules

Tags: database, apache-camel, activemq-classic, fuseesb, dmz

we want to transfer big amount of data from one mysql database(database1) to a remote database(database2). the local database(database1) is isolated with the help of dmz, implemented by firewall rules. firewall rule, open and close the connection port for every 15 minutes.(the port is open for 15 minutes and will be close for next 15 minutes.) I need to transfer my data from database1 into database2 in order they have been received to database1 and without any data lost.
(for example msg1,msg2,msg3,...)

[image]

I've tried using a activemq broker between two databases. but when connection is interrupted for 15 minutes, some of my data will be lost. and I can not recognize them from others.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What port opens and closes? Is this HTTP? Or, is ActiveMq itself crossing the wall?

Comment: thanks for your response @DariusX. activemq port:61616-firewall is between database1 and broker- we can use some other scenario instead of using a broker in dmz, our main problem is too transfer data from database1 to database2 with that 15 min disconnection condition.actually we used broker for persisting data but there is no force to use it.

Comment: So, do you have two applications, one inside and one outside the DMZ. A diagram would help. Right now, I am picturing this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F7l0Fu2zer2V54VxcUdHPL9aUKgqr8a9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DariusX. yes, this is exactly what I want, and I can not determine which messages are not received  to the broker when firewall close the port for 15 min, and also where(from which id) to start sending data again to the broker. because I need to send data by saving their order. thanks so much for your respone

Comment: So, do you have two applications -- both using Camel -- one inside the DMZ and one outside the DMZ ?

Comment: @DariusX. yes,tha's right. I have two application, one inside the dmz and one outside of that. Do you have better idea for it?

Comment: @DariusX. Could you please help me with that? Any suggestion will be helpful. thank.